# Meaning of いいようにしなさい

Tags: grammar, verbs

Someone did tell me this:

> 龍ちゃんの、いいようにしなさい。

However, how is it actually translated?

Could it be:

> It's alright if it's Ryu's 
>   I don't mind if it's Ryu's

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「龍{りゅう}ちゃんの、いいようにしなさい。」

「いいようにする」 is a fixed expression meaning "***to do as one pleases***".

So, the phrase in question means:

> "Do as you please, Ryuu-chan!"

The speaker is talking to Ryuu-chan.

Comment: So, after all the speaker doesn't mind it, and he/she could be mean it as; Yes, please!  ??

Comment: Doesn't mind what?  That is not easy to answer without more context provided, but in general, the expression describes the speaker's permission or consent for the other person to do something.

Comment: Well, I asked if it's okay to use a photo of  him and me as facebook profile photo.

Comment: I'm not sure that you should interpret it as a "Yes, please" because that's very emphatic but it is however probably closer to the English expression "Go right ahead" which is permissive.